# Consequence of Lemma 01RE in Stacks project

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

> [Lemma 01RE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RA). Let $j:U→X$ be an open immersion of schemes. Then U is scheme theoretically dense in X if and only if $\mathscr O_X→j_*\mathscr O_U$ is injective

I am surprised by this lemma on Stacks Project as by definition, an open immersion is an homeomorphism $U \simeq V \subset X$ where $V$ is open topological space, and $j_*\mathscr O_U \cong \mathscr O_X$

So as a consequence, every image of open immersion over $X$ is scheme theoretically dense in $X$.

Does it make sense?

Thank you.

Comment: You have the wrong definition for an open immersion. See [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01HE) in Stacks, for instance. (Your conclusion is also incorrect, but you should resolve the definitional issue first.)

Comment: I thought that it is equivalent, in a morphism of schemes, to have $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_ Y \cong \mathcal{O}_ X$ or to have $\mathcal{O}_ Y \cong f_* \mathcal{O}_ X$?